# Radiobuttons not working with jquery append?

Tags: jquery

I append jquery each function radio button like this;

```
$.each(dt, function (i, dt) {
 $('#tblCevaplar').append("<tr><td style='width:40px'> <input type='radio' name='radio"+i+"'  id='radio"+i+"' class='Radio' /><label for='radio11'> " +"</td><td>'" +dt.Cevap + "</td></tr>");
});
```

html

```
  <div class="row">
        <div class="col s12 m6 l6">
            <div class="card">
                <label id="soru" style="color: #000000; font-size: 20px"></label>
                <div class="card-content">
                    <div id="striped-table">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col s12">
                                <table>
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Cevaplar
                                            </th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody id="tblCevaplar">
                                    </tbody>

                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

The added radio button can't be selected. Where could the problem be?

Comment: are you trying to get a button group ?

Comment: Please click the `<>` snippet editor and add relevant HTML and jQuery to show a [mcve] - it sounds like a possible CSS issue

Comment: I Modified a bit to get it working and it works for me. Close your label tag <label for='radio11' /> and set that radio label 'for' as radio + i.

Comment: @L0uis this working but  I can choose both like checkbox.

Comment: I don't understand your question then, sorry.

Comment: @L0uis i want to use radiobutton(only 1 select) but now i can choose all the buttons I added.

Comment: @serhathss  check my solution once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do changes:-

1.add common `name` for each radio-box so that one at a time can be selected.

2.`<label>` need to be `closed`.

3.`'` is unnecessary here `'" +dt.Cevap + "` , so remove it.

So code needs to be:-

```
$.each(dt, function (i, dt) {
  $('#tblCevaplar').append("<tr><td style='width:40px'> <input type='radio' name='radio' class='Radio' /><label for='radio"+i+"'></label> " +"</td><td>" +dt.Cevap + "</td></tr>");
});
```

***Working snippet:-***

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   dt = [{'Cevap':1},{'Cevap':2}];
  $.each(dt, function (i, dt) {
   $('#tblCevaplar').append("<tr><td style='width:40px'> <input type='radio' name='radio' class='Radio' /><label for='radio"+i+"'></label> " +"</td><td>" +dt.Cevap + "</td></tr>");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col s12 m6 l6">
      <div class="card">
          <label id="soru" style="color: #000000; font-size: 20px"></label>
          <div class="card-content">
              <div id="striped-table">
                  <div class="row">
                      <div class="col s12">
                          <table>
                              <thead>
                                  <tr>
                                      <th>Cevaplar
                                      </th>
                                  </tr>
                              </thead>
                              <tbody id="tblCevaplar">
                              </tbody>

                          </table>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
```

Comment: @serhathss  glad to help you :):)